# Can I provide an encrypted string to users and be sure it is safe for 1-2 hours

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption

We were making kind of a simple game,
in which:

- Users receive the `next number of play` as an `encrypted string` **Before** they play
- **After** they play, the encryption `password` is provided to them to check the play number was correct.
- Each encrypted string is `only valid for 1-2 hours` and number of play , verificating string and encrypted string is regenerated again after that time
- The encrypted string includes a verification (5 char) code so both users and we can make sure Decryption process was successful

***Sample Character to get Encrypted*** (`QQ9LU` is random verification code provided to user before the play):

> Next Play Number: 8 - Verify String: QQ9LU

**Sample Encrypted String (provided to user before play):**

> NXRykKOv3B6kuu4Ke3svp7HH3enNiqIZrJSXJiF54QkHHjtXgqpUXxyuP7YUNICeFLg==

**Sample Password (provided after play):**

Please note this is generated randomly for each encryption

> FA00RDjA77hlOzcOzH6kuGcc29CyM7Hw

We use CodeIgniter 2.2.2 Encryption Class to encrypt/decrypt strings

**Encryption Method Info:**

- Function Used: `$this->encrypt->encode($msg, $pass);` with random pass each time
- Cipher is CodeIgniter 2 default `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256`
- Mcrypt mode is `MCRYPT_MODE_CBC`

### My Questions are:

1. Can i trust that users cannot break the encrypted string (and know the number of play before they get the password) in 1-2 hours (aside from getting lucky)
2. Is placing random verification code `Verify String: T3YH4` in there good or bad? does is affect security? (this is to verify decryption result was successful, also we added it because the only variable in each string was a single digit, for example only number 8 changes to 7, so we wanted to add more variable characters to the string to possibly have a better security)

Any other suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Put the code into a database at your end and authenticate against that. Add the time element.

Comment: @EdHeal I have done that, question is not about how to implement this, it is already implemented and the work is done

Comment: if you pick the right crypt algo and key, then you can be relatively sure that the only people cheating your game are various bored nerds over at the NSA...

Comment: Maybe I'm just dumb, but I really can't understand what is going on here at all after reading it like 3 times. Perhaps if you provided some sort of pseudo code. Maybe state more clearly what exactly is being encrypted, what exactly is being verified, where the verification code comes from, what exactly you are trying to prevent by doing it like this, etc.

Comment: What I can say to you is: you are using the right cipher. Rijndael is the standard encryption function and are currently considered secure. If you are sure that your key are secured and the user cannot access it before he should, I would say yes, you are secure. Perhaps, I didn't understand the role of the "Verify string", can you explain better?

Comment: @DineiA.Rockenbach Yes passwords are also encrypted before saving,  as a matter of fact i added this random verify code to have more variables characters in each string, because i thought only changing a number , 1 to 2 e.g. might affect the security and breaking the encryption might be easier, ill edit the question a little

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answers:

1. From a technical POV, what you're doing is unsafe, although it might be enough for just a 2-hour timeframe.
2. What you're trying to do here is called "message authentication", but that's not how it should be done, which in turn does impact security. You should use a HMAC instead.

My advice would be to upgrade to CodeIgniter 3 (CI2 will stop receiving even security updates in a few months) as soon as possible, and use its new Encryption library instead. That will make it safe for years, not hours.

Long answer:

The encryption library should do both encryption *and* authentication for you, but unfortunately the `CI_Encrypt` class itself is badly written and lacking a lot of functionality (such as authentication), which is why it was DEPRECATED and is being replaced by a new (`CI_Encryption`) library in CodeIgniter 3.

Explaining all the flaws in here would be quite the task, so I'd rather link you to an [external article (not self-promoting, don't worry)](http://timoh6.github.io/2014/06/16/PHP-data-encryption-cheatsheet.html), which does that quite nicely if you're interested in the low-level details.

No matter which library you use however, one thing must be noted - a password is not the same thing as an encryption key.

Passwords have a varying length and are used by humans, which means that they must be readable by humans, and that in turn limits them to a certain set of characters.

Encryption keys on the other hand have a fixed length (each encryption algorithm is designed to work with a specific key length; for Rijndael-256 that's 32 bytes, which you seem to match) and are not limited to human-readable characters (which means more entropy and therefore more security) - they represent raw binary data.

Anything else can be controlled (and therefore automatically done) by a library, but if you pass a password instead of a key - that's what the library will use, so you should take care of that.

Comment: "The encryption library should do both encryption and authentication for you" in the correct order. That's kind of a big deal. :P (But yes, Narf's answer is the correct one!)

Answer (score 3):

The best and simple way to do that is to use the filesystem functions to create a simple text file for each user in non public path with two lines, the first of them is a unique random string (long string varied in length) and the second is the number.

Then using `sha1_file` get the hash value of the file then store it in the database related to its path and creating time, then send this hash to the user.

After the user has played, check the value by another script that get the value of the hash from the database, then read the file and parse its second line to display the number.

By this way, you have gave the user a hash not for a string, but it for a file and cracking it to get the file back is not simple as to be done in two hours.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving your Encryption/Decryption logic to client side. Hacker will easily identify how your password and encryption strings are being match.

Many framework have their own password creationg and compare logics. Yii using SALT and other features like SHA1 etc...

Keep it simple and keep all things at your end. Generate your encryption things and store at your end. Follow simple steps,

1. Generate encryption password (using SALT and/or other encryption tools) and store at your end
2. Ask client (user) to enter their password (key) and get at server side
3. Convert your password (key) to encryption password and compare

[CPasswordHelper](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPasswordHelper) will be helpful for you. Try to download Yii source code and put out their logic for you.

Hope that helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a fun game!
I am assuming you are creating these strings in files on a filesystem. If you were hosting them on some web application that would assume different techniques to break the string.

Adding a code to the end of the string is called salting the string. While this makes the string harder to guess, if you are adding a hardcoded salt instead of a randomly generated salt it can still be easily broken by brute force methods.

I would try using a one-way hashed string for the password and storing that in a database. The user is unable to decrypt the string and has to just provide a matching password to gain access to your string. It is possible for programs to break one-way hashed strings but I find it unlikely someone will be smart enough to do that if they are in college and only have two hours. It takes alot of domain knowledge and experience to start generating one-way hashed strings to brute force it.

In addition you are probably safe with the method you are doing currently, students will not likely be able to break a string in 2 hours unless they are familiar with advanced encryption hacking scripts that take some work to find. I am guessing they will do trial and error, using different decryption libraries similar to the example you provide and hoping they get lucky with the library of strings they are trying to match against yours.

Also information is important with any type of encryption. Telling someone you are adding a 5 code salt to your string, will give them some insight into how your encryption algorithm works. They can then try methods of breaking it based on the information you give them. Try the same thing with your own algorithm and leave the students in the dark, I doubt anyone will break anything in the time alotted. Alot of hacking techniques involve going through an information gathering process where the hacker scopes out or maps a system before trying to attack it.